# How to display text in a ListBox?

Tags: asp.net, listbox

I'm using a ListBox to display fairly long text items (500 characters).  If an item is too long it will go out the side of the ListBox and not be fully displayed.  How can I get items in the ListBox to wrap?  Also, is it possible to put some sort of separator between each item?

Here is a screen shot with the last item being cut off.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ec46dc6f71.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ec46dc6f71.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happens, most people resort to using a Datagrid with 1 column.